# How do I unlock the Shaymin quest at Floaro Gardens in Pokémon Legends: Arceus without having played Pokémon Sword or Shield?

Tags: pokemon-legends-arceus

I want to unlock the quest for Shaymin in the Floaro Gardens in *Pokémon Legends: Arceus*, but I didn't play *Pokémon Sword* or *Shield*. Is there any way to unlock it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a Sword or Shield save on your Switch, you will unlock a quest for [Shaymin Land Forme](https://rankedboost.com/pokemon-legends-arceus/shaymin-land/).  You cannot unlock that without having Sword or Shield game data on your Switch; however, you don't have to play very *far* into the game (you just need the save to exist), so it is relatively easy to unlock this using a friend's help who does have a Sword or Shield cartridge.

Comment: How far are we talking about? And i already far in pokemon legends arceus

Comment: As far as I know, you literally just need a save to exist, so far enough in the game to save it once.  A few minutes at most.

Comment: Thank you for this